# git mergin 2 old commits and put the merge in origin:master head

Tags: git, merge

I need to make a new merge of 2 commits and the total merge put in Head of `origin:master`.

What is the easiest way??

Comment: Is one of these commits already at the tip of your `master` branch?

Comment: edit : avoid using Internet slangs in your questions/answers.

Comment: I actually like the "war" sentence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably not enough information in your question to give a good answer, but here are pointers that may be useful.

In git, you create a merge with the command `git merge <OTHER-BRANCH>`, which will always merge the other branch into your current commit - usually that's the tip of the branch that you're on.  So, in the simplest situation, if one of your commits is at the tip of `master`, and the other one is called `B`, then you can do the following:

- Make sure that you're on `master` with `git checkout master`
- Merge `A` into `master` with: `git merge B`
- Push that result to the `master` branch in the `origin` repository: `git push origin master`

---

If one of your commits isn't at the tip of `master` - let's say it's called `A` - then you can still create a merge commit from `A` and `B` with:

```
git checkout A
git merge B
```

However, this merged commit won't contain the history of `master`, so if you push that to `master` in `origin`, that will rewrite the history of `master` in that repository, which creates problems if you're collaborating.  If you do want to go ahead with that nonetheless, you can "force" the push with:

```
git push -f origin HEAD:master
```

... and to avoid confusion, you would probably want to also reset your `master` branch to point to that commit:

```
# Check that "git status" is clean, to avoid losing uncommitted work:
git status

# Create a new branch that points to where master used to be:
git branch old-master master

# Switch to the master branch:
git checkout master

# Reset the master branch to point to the merge commit you created above:
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting 2 specific commits, `git cherry-pick` will suffice. Do that from a new branch or on master directly, if you dare (master is usually reserved for what is stable or released - do not break master!)